# How can I move the input processor with the camera in LibGDX?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, input, libgdx

I recently started programming an app in LibGDX. With this app, one can only now press on boxes which are then filled in blue.

In principle everything works. The problem is only if I move the orthographic camera, or start to zoom, then my input processor still remains in the same place.
In short. Because the camera is moved or zoomed, the input does not work properly.

I have two times here Schreenshots attached so you can see what I mean.
The red dots are always where I pressed.

Regards Timux ;D
[Here it works correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41EnJ.png)

[No more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PadgQ.png)

Comment: What do you mean that the InputProcessor "stays in the same place"? InputProcessor does not have a location, so I do not understand. It will help a lot if you show some code to show what you are doing.

Comment: I also suggest that you learn how to debug your code. Add Gdx.app.log() calls or use the Android Studio debugger to view values of variables and flow execution of your code.

Answer (score 0):

No problem when I move or zoom my camera, I've tested, you can check this.
May be you're not using `unproject()` method of camera that translate a point given in screen coordinates to world space.

```
public class GdxText extends ApplicationAdapter implements InputProcessor {

    OrthographicCamera cam;
    Texture texture;
    Sprite firstSprite,secondSprite;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Vector3 vector3;


    @Override
    public void create() {

        vector3=new Vector3();
        cam=new OrthographicCamera();

        texture=new Texture("badlogic.jpg");

        float w=Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        float h=Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

        spriteBatch=new SpriteBatch();

        firstSprite=new Sprite(texture);
        firstSprite.setSize(100,100);
        firstSprite.setPosition(w/2-150,h/2-50);

        secondSprite=new Sprite(texture);
        secondSprite.setSize(100,100);
        secondSprite.setPosition(w/2+50,h/2-50);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        spriteBatch.begin();
        firstSprite.draw(spriteBatch);
        secondSprite.draw(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

        cam.setToOrtho(false,width,height);
        cam.update();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {

        if(keycode== Input.Keys.UP) {
            cam.zoom -= cam.zoom * .1;
            cam.update();
        }else if(keycode==Input.Keys.DOWN) {
            cam.zoom += cam.zoom * .1;
            cam.update();
        }

        if(keycode== Input.Keys.LEFT) {
           cam.position.add(2f,0,0);

            cam.update();
        }else if(keycode==Input.Keys.RIGHT) {
            cam.position.add(-2f,0,0);
            cam.update();
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

        vector3.set(screenX,screenY,0);
        Vector3 ori=cam.unproject(vector3);
        if(firstSprite.getBoundingRectangle().contains(ori.x,ori.y))
            System.out.println("Touch on First Sprite");

        if(secondSprite.getBoundingRectangle().contains(ori.x,ori.y))
            System.out.println("Touch on Second Sprite");

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        spriteBatch.dispose();
        texture.dispose();
    }
}
```